# How to set :focus background color on the button

Tags: html, css

My problem so little but I am very confused where I am going wrong.

I can not set the `:focus` background color on my button.

**My css**

```
span {background: #000; display:inline-block; padding: 13px 1% 7px; text-align: center; width: 50px; cursor:pointer}
label {background: #fff; display: inline-block; height: 3px; margin: 0 0 5px; vertical-align: middle; width: 100%; cursor:pointer}
span:hover label{background:red;}
span:active label{background:green;}
span:focus label{background:#0ff;}
```

and my HTML

```
<span id="open">
 <label></label>
 <label></label>
 <label></label>
</span>
```

Please tell me where I going wrong.

Comment: check this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/anmol1976/rxb9ubxr/

Comment: focus color is already there. What actually you want?

Comment: Hover this button you see the button change into red color and in active the color change into green but i want when i click the button then button change fixed background color like blue not white, red or green

Comment: Try giving the span a tabindex attribute. PS. There is a typo in your question title.

Comment: Check http://jsfiddle.net/rxb9ubxr/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `tabindex` attribute to your span.

```
<span id="open" tabindex="0">
```

That will allow it to be focusable. Then you can set the focus by clicking or tabbing. There is nothing wrong with your CSS--it works as is. See http://jsfiddle.net/rxb9ubxr/1/.

Because you have specified the `focus` rule last, once the element gains focus, the `active` rule will never be applied. To allow the `active` rule to be applied even when the element has the focus (in other words, to change the color during clicking), reverse the order of your `active` and `focus` rules.

```
span:hover  label {background: red;}
span:focus  label {background: #0ff;}
span:active label {background: green;}
```

Comment: Ok, that's fine i check your given link but in this link button not show active color that is green.

Comment: @AnmolRatanMohla because active and focus behave like same so you cant get both event at same time.

Comment: If I understand your comment correctly, you can obtain the desired behavior by swapping the order of the rules for active and focus.